# process.env.NODE_ENV is in development still it shows unexpected behivour

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables, development-environment

I'm running my node server in development environment but in my server file it shows unexpected behaviour

my script is as fallows:

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
console.log("------------------------------");
console.log("envenv",typeof env,env);
console.log("0",typeof env);
console.log("00",env);
console.log("2",env.toString()=='development');
console.log("3",""+env.toString()=='production');
console.log("2",env==='development');
console.log("3",env=="production");
console.log("------------------------------");
```

> but it gives following output

```
------------------------------
envenv string 'development'
0 string
00 'development'
2 false
3 false
2 false
3 false
------------------------------
```

> When I tried any of following it worked fine

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV.trim(); 
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase();
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV.replace("","");

.............
```

or any method other then toString() which are in prototype of String class
It worked fine

Answer (score 3):

The environment variable NODE_ENV contains superfluous `'`. Something went wrong when setting the environment variable. For windows system use

```
> SET NODE_ENV=development
```

instead of

```
> SET NODE_ENV='development'
```

That should fix the issue.

To get the current value of NODE_ENV printed on the command line use

```
> echo %NODE_ENV%
```

That should print

```
> development
```

Without any " or '

Answer (score 1):

How do you set the `NODE_ENV`? I'm working on windows and I've just spent some time fighting the same problem and discovered that it was because my npm script looked like `SET NODE_ENV=production && do everything else` so `NODE_ENV` was actually containing the whitespace as the last character which for some reason wasn't displayed in a console (I've done kind of the same set of tests as yours, but I also checked lengths of my strings and discovered that NODE_ENV is one symbol wider than it should be). Changing my script to `SET NODE_ENV=production&& do everything else` solved the issue.

Comment: I'm using set NODE_ENV=development && ...other, inside script in package.json

Comment: @AkhileshKumar, then as I've explained, remove the whitespace before '&&' and check if it will solve your problem. `NODE_ENV=development&&`.

Comment: @aush That was the answer. I had the same problem and it solved!

Answer (score 1):

> console.log("00",env);

this should print `00 development` instead of `00 'development'`

You should set your env again.