# Why does this always evaluate to false?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use the `NODE_DEV` environment variable within my javascript application run specific code conditionally. I therefor set variable inside my script definition, which I later use like this: `npm run dev`.

However my function `isDevelopment()` always returns `false`, though outputting `process.env.NODE_ENV` correctly returns `development`. I have no idea what is wrong with my comparsion. I have tried all kinds of combination, like `'`, `"`, `==`, `===` without luck.

What am I doing wrong here?

**package.json**

```
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    // ...
    "dev": "set NODE_ENV=development && npx npm-run-all --parallel run_nodemon run_browser-sync",
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

**app.js**

```
function isDevelopment() {
    console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV); // outputs as expected: development

    return process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";
}

console.log(isDevelopment()); // outputs: false
```

Comment: try NODE_ENV=development npx npm-run-all --parallel run_nodemon run_browser-sync

Comment: @cnexans, thanks for the quick reply. Tried that as well, doesn't change a thing. I am on Windows btw.

Comment: try process.env.NODE_ENV.trim() to make sure there isn't trailing spaces which won't show in in console.log

Comment: The environment variable does get set correctly.

Comment: Calling `trim()` did the trick, so I still don't understand why. Even when setting my env var like this: `"dev": "set NODE_ENV=\"development\" && npx npm-run-all --parallel run_nodemon run_browser-sync",`. Crazy

Comment: Look like it's a Windows-specific issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35176569/4494577 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529870/ifprocess-env-node-env-production-always-false

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if(process.env.NODE\_ENV === 'production') always false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529870/ifprocess-env-node-env-production-always-false)